# webpack-dev-server (e.g Angular) and webRoot in VSC Chrome Debugger

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server

We have been working on a project using `webpack-dev-server`, and have a hard time understanding `webRoot` in `launch.json` of Visual Studio Code, given the provided Chrome debugger documentation.

The Chrome debugger [README](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) says:

> “...set webRoot to the directory that files are served from.”

With `webpack-dev-server` (used by Angular and several other frameworks), the content is served from memory, not from any given directory on the drive. For example, the `dist` folder does not contain the latest version of the build. If you make a change to source files when `webpack-dev-server` is running, only the version in memory will be updated. In fact, to avoid confusions, many frameworks delete the `dist` folder when launching the `webpack-dev-server`.

From the [webpack-dev-server docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html):

> “…This modified bundle is served from memory at the relative path
>   specified in publicPath (see API). It will not be written to your
>   configured output directory…”

Since the directory it is served from is not explicitly on drive, it is not clear to us what the `webRoot` folder needs to be, and why.

As a side note, forcing `webpack-dev-server` (e.g angular) to not delete the `dist` folder, then setting `webRoot` to the `dist` folder, makes the `.scripts` command show a connection between localhost and files on the drive (as I believe it should). This is not preferred though, as `dist` does not hold the latest version, and one would have to change the default Angular behavior.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.